# why is are my brackets not working properly

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game in unity, and I am currently working on an inventory system, *this isn't completely relevant* I wrote most of the code away from my main computer so I couldn't test it, so obviously there were a lot of errors when I went to test it, but one of them I couldn't figure out, which is in the start function for unity, it was saying that I needed a } when I had one, here was my exact code.*without putting in the usings*

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
  void Start()
  {
    Public InvSlot[] Slots = new InvSlot[23];
  }
}
```

and it was saying that I needed a } for the start function when I have one

Comment: Typo?  Get rid of `Public`.  (1) The keyword is `public`, not `Public`.  (2) You're declaring a local variable and access modifiers don't apply in that context.  (Unless you want this to be a class-level field?  In which case move it outside the method and fix the `public` keyword.)

Comment: Did you intend `Slots` to be a local variable of the `Start` method, or did you intend it to be a public field of the `Inventory` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible fixes depending on what you intended:

A) `Slots` is a public field of the `Inventory` class:

```cs
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
  public InvSlot[] Slots = new InvSlot[23];

  void Start()
  {
  }
}
```

B) `Slots` is a local variable in the `Start` method:

```cs
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
  void Start()
  {
    InvSlot[] Slots = new InvSlot[23];
  }
}
```